# WebViewControl.java:122 cannot find symbol when packaging Unreal 4 game for Android

Tags: android, unreal-4, mobile

Whenever I try to package my project for Android I get this.

```
Z:\app\src\main\java\com\epicgames\ue4\WebViewControl.java:122: error: cannot find symbol
```

My setup:

[image: Screenshot of configuration]

- Android SDK build tool: 31.0.0
- NDK: 21.4
- Android SDK command line tool: 5.0

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try remove 33 SDK with Android Studio, like on this video https://youtu.be/Xq0AcQ1msTg

Comment: This seems a link-only answer. Please expand it to include details and information from the video, so that the answer still holds in case of link rot.